# Dos Subprogramas en un programa (androidstudio)

Tags: java, android-studio

bueno les cuento mi idea o problema, el tema es que tengo un subprograma A que debe estar activo en todo momento mientras la app este activada, pero necesito que si ocurre una acción(como tocar un botón) se active el subprograma B sin desactivarse el subprograma A (el subprograma B es esporádico, no continuo como A)

El tema es que no he logrado unir estos dos programas en uno, siendo A en principio un ciclo while(true)

Tienen alguna idea de como hacer funcionar estos dos programas a la vez sin que A se detenga?

Comment: ¿Podrías poner el código de A y de B? Sin verlo no se entiende qué defines tú como "subprograma". Mira a ver si [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24687007/6883957)  sugerencia  te ayuda

Comment: Pon el código para que podamos ver a que te refieres como "subprograma" y entender mejor el problema. Probablemente lo que necesites es hacer el uso de Hilos(Thread) dentro del aplicación